# Upload an image in .net Core

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to upload an image in .NET core, but I it gives me an error while the stream copy to another stream to save the data. When it runs as local server, it works perfectly and I upload all execution files to Linux (Ubuntu) server, then the following error has displayed on the console window. Server location is in India. Thank you.

```
 Unhandled exception. System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed.
 Object name: 'SafeHandle'.
 at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
 at Interop.Sys.PRead(SafeHandle fd, Byte* buffer, Int32 bufferSize, Int64 fileOffset)
 at System.IO.RandomAccess.ReadAtOffset(SafeFileHandle handle, Span`1 buffer, Int64 
 fileOffset)
 at 
 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.ThreadPoolValueTaskSource.ExecuteInternal()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
 at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.ThreadPoolValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 
 token)
 at 
 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.
 ThreadPoolValueTaskSource.System.Threading.Tasks. 
 Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, 
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ReferenceReadStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, 
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsync>g__Core|29_0(Stream source, Stream destination, Int32 
 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile.CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken 
 cancellationToken)
 at ContractAPI.Helper.AppBaseService.CreateFile(String savePath, IFormFile formFile) in 
  AppBaseService.cs:line 38
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
 at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.<>c. 
 <.cctor>b__6_0(QueueUserWorkItemCallback quwi)
 at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
 at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
 at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
 at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
  
 public class Program
 {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
      }   
       
      public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            }); 
 }  


 public class Startup
 {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddDbContext<ContractMakerContext>(options =>
       {
           options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
       });

       services.AddScoped<ICompanyInfoService, CompanyInfoService>();
       services.AddControllers();
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ContractAPI v1"));
        }
         
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
 }

 public interface ICompanyInfoService
 {
    Task<ResponseUserCompanyInfo> updateUserCompanyInfoWithFile(CompanyInfoWithFile info);
 }

 public class CompanyInfoService : ICompanyInfoService
 {

  public static IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
    public CompanyInfoService(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

 public async Task<ResponseUserCompanyInfo> updateUserCompanyInfoWithFile(CompanyInfoWithFile info)
 {
     ResponseUserCompanyInfo response = new ResponseUserCompanyInfo();
     

     CreateFile($"{_environment.WebRootPath}{Constants.SaveCompanyImagePath}", info.company_logo_url); 
     return response;
 }
 
 private async void CreateFile(string savePath, IFormFile formFile)
 {
    if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
    }

    if (formFile.Length <= 0) return;

    using (var filestream = File.Create($"{savePath}{formFile.FileName}"))
    {
         await formFile.CopyToAsync(filestream); //Problem is here
    }
  } 
} 



[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CompanyInfoController : ControllerBase
{
   ICompanyInfoService _service;
   public CompanyInfoController(ICompanyInfoService service)
   {
       _service = service;
   }

   [HttpPost("updateUserCompanyInfoWithFile")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> updateUserCompanyInfoWithFile([FromForm] CompanyInfoWithFile info)
    { 
        ResponseUserCompanyInfo response = await Service.updateUserCompanyInfoWithFile(info);
        return MakeResponse(response, response.error_code);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you build the project for Linux server?

Comment: Actually I am creating an API for my mobile app. Everything works fine so far except this uploading part. So when you publish your project the .dll file will be created as well, and you can run your project in Linux based on that .dll file.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `CreateFile` as returning a `Task`:

```
private async Task CreateFile(string savePath, IFormFile formFile)
```

Otherwise you end up with something called a "fire and forget" method: the server cannot know when your method is done copying the data because it doesn't have a task it can await, so it disposes the `IFormFile` before you're done using it.

In general, avoid `async void` methods, they come with a load of caveats.